# Disable linker warning in Visual Studio 2015 (LNK4221,LNK4006)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker, suppress-warnings

How to suppress (hide) LNK4221,4006 warning in Visual Studio 2015?

> D:\solutionFolder\projectFolder\OgreHlmsPbs_d.lib(OgreHlmsPbs_d.dll)  1   __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
>   already defined in OgreOverlay_d.lib(OgreOverlay_d.dll); second
>   definition ignored    LNK4006
>
> D:\solutionFolder\projectFolder\OgreHlmsPbs_d.lib(OgreHlmsPbs_d.dll)  1   This
>   object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols,
>   so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this
>   library   LNK4221

The program run fine.

I use librarian (same as a SO question : [LNK4006, LNK4221 warnings when using static library that includes another static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103488/lnk4006-lnk4221-warnings-when-using-static-library-that-includes-another-static/30537907)).

**I have tried :-**

- Linker > all options  > additional option = `/ignore:4221,4006`
- Linker > Command Line > additional option = `/ignore:4221,4006`
- Librarian > all options  > additional option = `/ignore:4221,4006`
- Librarian > Command Line  > additional option = `/ignore:4221,4006`

I have set it to both user-project and the static library.

I have also tried `/ignore:4221` alone for the above 4 combination, it can't suppress LINK4221.
 Capital `/IGNORE:4221` doesn't work either.

All of the above don't solve. Are there any other combination?

I don't want to modify my code e.g.

```
__declspec( dllexport ) void getRidOfLNK4221(){}
```

**I have read :-**

- [How to eliminate Warning LNK4221?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854324/how-to-eliminate-warning-lnk4221)  and [Visual C++: How to disable specific linker warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661606/visual-c-how-to-disable-specific-linker-warnings)  (provide some of the above non-working solutions)
- http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/msvc/link/link/options/ignore.htm implies that both 4221 and 4006 can be disable.

I guess this version of Visual Studio (2015) may have different way to fix this issue.

### Further investigation

After posting the question, I found  :-

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7whw3f3.aspx :  The error is about not found `.pdb`.
- [How to remove warning LNK4099: PDB 'lib.pdb' was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843883/how-to-remove-warning-lnk4099-pdb-lib-pdb-was-not-found)

I started to think that using **librarian** is probably not a good idea in the first place.

However, even I don't set **librarian**, I still get this warning for my own empty `MyClass.cpp`.
Therefore, this problem is probably not related to **librarian**.

> D:\solutionFolder\projectFolder\MyClass.obj   1   This object file does
>   not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be
>   used by any link operation that consumes this library LNK4221

Comment: Not sure if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661606/visual-c-how-to-disable-specific-linker-warnings

Comment: For me, adding "/ignore:4221" to Librarian additional options of the static library project worked in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.